# How to disable additional message about XHR in chrome console

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, console, xmlhttprequest

[image]

How to disable additional message about xhr which display with **bold** font? I don't really need this information, but I don't know how to disable it. When I check "Log XMLHttpRequests" in chrome console. This setting only allow to remove message which display in console with **blue title**, messages with **bold** title don't removing.